# How do I have separate devices open new tabs in Firefox in a Work/Personal Container by default?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, multi-account-containers

I have a work device and a personal device, and wish to have the work device open all new tabs in the Work container while my home device open all new tabs in my Personal container.

I am aware that I can just manually open new Work container tabs, and that I can set the extension to open specific sites in containers, but I wish to be able to press 'Ctrl + t' to open tabs in Work container and Personal container for my respective devices while remaining site-agnostic.

Is there a method?